# Dockerfile not reading values from the .env file

Tags: docker

In my `.env` file I have setup the USERNAME:
`USERNAME=myuser`

When I do a docker compose build, it is unable to resolve the placeholders $USERNAME in the Dockerfile.

My Dockerfile:

```
FROM busybox:latest as build
ENV USERNAME=$USERNAME
```

.
.
.

How can I achieve this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the reason - the .env file must reside in the same folder as docker-compose.yml

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.5'

services:
    container:
        build:
            context: .
            args:
                USERNAME: ${USERNAME} # from .env file
        env_file:
            - .env
```

Dockerfile

```
# docker-compose args
ARG USERNAME 
...
```

.env

```
USERNAME=value
```

If you not use .env file, just remove env_file properties and set env in args.

Comment: When I do a docker compose build, it says:
time="2023-01-30T16:31:38+05:30" level=warning msg="The \"USERNAME\" variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string."